# Third party payment providers and responsive web design

Tags: asp.net, responsive-design, payment-processing, realex-payments-api

I am looking to integrate a third party payment provider with my ASP.NET application which implements a responsive web design, i.e., it is designed to render well on mobile devices and scale up to desktop.

When integrating with the third party payment provider — Realex Payments — I noticed that this is not designed to render well on mobile devices.

Are there any third party payment providers that have a more mobile friendly look and feel?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, which is why it's a comment, not an answer, but Realex also provide a service where the customer gives *you* their credit card details, and you pass them on to Realex for processing. This allows you to be in complete control of the customer experience. Of course, it also means you need a security certificate, and you need to worry about the liability of holding credit card data, even if it's only very temporarily (just long enough to accept the data from the customer and pass it on to Realex).

Answer (score 0):

Try `Google Checkout`  [API](https://developers.google.com/checkout/)

This is payment gateway facility by Google for mobile applications only and this you can set easily in your responsive design while using Media Query.